# O(2) equivariant isomorphism between harmonic polynomials and $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, representation-theory, harmonic-functions, orthogonal-matrices

Write $H^k(\mathbb{C}^2)$ for the space of harmonic polynomials on $\mathbb{C^2}$ of degree $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. It can be easily shown that
$$H^k(\mathbb{C}^2) = \mathbb{C}(z_1 + i z_2)^k + \mathbb{C}(z_1 - iz_2)^k$$
This space is an $O(2)$-module with the standard action given by $p \mapsto p(B^{-1}\cdot)$, for $B\in O(2)$.

We also consider the $O(2)$-module $\mathbb{C}^2_k$ defined by $O(2) \rightarrow GL_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C}^2), B \mapsto B^k$.

**I know that this two $O(2)$-modules are isomorphic, that is $H^k(\mathbb{C}^2) \simeq \mathbb{C}^2_k$, but I don't know how to prove it.**

The only case I could prove is the trivial one, namely the case $k = 1$. For this case, the map below is an $O(2)$-equivariant isomorphism.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
H^1(\mathbb{C}^2) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2_1\\
a(z_1 + iz_2) + b(z_1 - iz_2) \mapsto a\begin{pmatrix}1\\i\end{pmatrix}+ b\begin{pmatrix}1\\-i\end{pmatrix}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}

When I try to do something similar for $k\geq 2$, the $O(2)$-equivariance fails.

Maybe I'm missing some facts of representation theory. Do you have any idea?

Edit: I managed to prove that the same map in arbitrary degree, that is
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
H^k(\mathbb{C}^2) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2_k\\
a(z_1 + iz_2)^k + b(z_1 - iz_2)^k \mapsto a\begin{pmatrix}1\\i\end{pmatrix}+ b\begin{pmatrix}1\\-i\end{pmatrix}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
Is an $SO(2)$-equivariant isomorphism, but I still have problems to prove the equivariance for reflections.

Comment: How is $B\mapsto B^k$ a representation of $O(2)$ if it's not a homomorphism?

Comment: You are totally right. The other day I computed the characters of the two "representations" defined in the question, and I got that for elements of $SO(2)$ the characters coincide, while for other elements of $O(2)$ the characters are not the same (thus the statement is not true in the first place).
But not only that, as you pointed out, the map $B \mapsto B^k$ does not define a representation of $O(2)$.

I have more information about this which I will share as an answer to my question, but thank you very much for your comment.